# Is a mutex capable of performing this

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, clipboard

I have a situation where I have multiple threads accessing the clipboard and performing an action with some sleeps. Basically I don't want to copy the wrong thing to the clipboard and perform something in an incorrect fashion.

Currently, I have an idea of using a mutex to lock a `std::string` variable and store the required data in it, then to the clipboard. After I finish the action, I unlock it. Then the other thread accesses the variable, then clipboard, and action.

As I have never used a mutex, my question is - will it work by just doing the above?

I'm using the following library to manage the clipboard: https://github.com/dacap/clip

Comment: A mutex can be used to protect the string from multiple threads accessing it at the same time. It sounds like you might want a [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to synchronize the order of the threads' access to the string.

Comment: Why are you using the clipboard to pass information between threads? That is not what it is meant for. It would be really useful if you could show your current code, maybe someone can offer a better solution.

Comment: I'm using the clipboard as my program interacts with a program that uses clipboard to paste a code.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the library, you may not need to use a `mutex` at all. For eg. the `set_text` function:

```
bool set_text(const std::string& value) {
  lock l;
  if (l.locked()) {
    l.clear();
    return l.set_data(text_format(), value.c_str(), value.size());
  }
  else
    return false;
}
```

You can see that a lock is being created (which locks the resource based on the os implementation at construction of `lock l`) which should provide you some thread safety.

Comment: That code does not make access `std::string` that `value` refers to thread safe.

Comment: @Slava True, but from the question, it seems like the OP is using a string that he intends to write from threads, so he can write to the clipboard. I was thinking that maybe the string is unnecasary, depending on the objective, you can just write directly to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, I have an idea of using a mutex to lock a `std::string` variable and store the required data in it, then to the clipboard.

From the way you explain this it is clear you do not understand how it works. Mutex does not lock a variable whatever type it has. Mutex is locked itself. And mutex has a property that only one thread can lock it at a time. Using that property you can organize your program the way so only one thread will access some critical data and that will make such access thread safe. It is not that you link a mutex to an unrelated variable, then that mutex would somehow lock that variable and make it thread safe. Now if you understand what is different btw those you would understand that yes you can make access to your `std::string` variable thread safe but that will require all threads accessing it doing that under mutex lock, not that only one thread locks it and all other will obey that lock magically.